# how to link jm reference software to opencv in visual studio 2010

Tags: .net

I got output for SIFT feature extraction of video using OPENCV 2.4.9.and I have run H.264 AVC using JM reference software.Now I have doubt in combining these two software. How to give output of JM reference software to OpenCV using visual studio 2010.